# Keep getting GET requests on my TCP server

Tags: python, curl, tcplistener, get-request

I have made a TCP server/listener script in python with a non-standard port, mostly to test and learn. I keep getting these seemingly random GET requests as follows:

```
GET /setup/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy
Accept: */*
```

I have been reading around about cURL and HTTP requests and as far as i can tell it tries to request a file.

That is not all however, as it also contains some characters that are not rendered (not shown) when i paste the request here. The python output looks like the following when i get it to print the input i get:

[image: Python output of GET request]

What is the purpose of these requests and are the square characters something else that just nothing?

Regards

Comment: Maybe you have a program that uses that port? My best guess would be that the port you opened your server on might be the same as that program, and thus you are receiving those requests instead of that program.

Comment: @EmanuelL I did a netstat -lptn and i didn't find any program that uses that port other than the python script that i am running. Could there be some program that doesn't show up on netstat? I am running on a raspberry pi and the port is 9090.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they're scanners. often it's viruses or hackers looking for vulnerable servers. the weird []'s you keep seeing seems to be the \r\n header-separators, it appears that your terminal have a problem displaying \r\n -style newlines.

> it tries to request a file.

correct, here it tries to fetch the file `/setup/index.jsp` - most likely there exist a server which has a vulnerability that can be detected from that specific file, and if you happened to have that file on the server, the scanner would most likely initiate an attack, trying to hack into your server via `/setup/index.jsp`

> What is the purpose of these requests

increasing the size of their botnet (people pay good money for access to lage botnets for DDoS attacks, ip spoofing and the like), looking for valuable information (is the server used to store credit card information?), stuff like that.

> are the square characters something else that just nothing?

the weird characters are carriage-return characters, it appears your terminal has a problem with them, or that your python program is corrupting the CrLf's before priting them to the terminal. (you can pipe the output to a file, and then view the output in a hex editor to confirm - if the hex editor says the newlines are 0D 0A, your terminal has a problem with carriage-return, but if it's not 0D 0A, your python app corrupted the data before printing it to the terminal.)